# How to select json path dot-notation for path list?

Tags: jsonpath, jayway

I need to return list of json paths using:

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder()
   .options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build();
List<String> pathList = using(conf).parse(json).read("$..author");
```

By default all paths will be in bracket-notation:

```
  "$['store']['book'][0]['author'],
   $['store']['book'][1]['author']"
```

Is it possible to change it to dot-notation?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately no. Only by custom regex replacement

Comment: The bracket notation is used because some attributes may contain whitespace or special characters.  dot notation doesn't work well in such cases.

Comment: Which regex you used? Can you please share?